# Multilevel regression modelling with replicate weights in stata

Tags: stata, multilevel-analysis, survey-weights

I'm analysing a data set to which I do not have full access but am allowed to submit a limited number stata commands. These data used a complex survey design which is obscured for privacy reasons. However, a series of 60 replicate weight variables have been created for weighting with the `svr` suite of commands.

Is it possible to perform multilevel logistic regression with the svr suite? If so, what commands should I use?

I'm fairly new to stata, but need to use it due to the privacy controls around these data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`svr` is a user-written alternative to Stata's native [`svy`](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/svy.pdf), which uses Taylor series linearization. The later can now accommodate multilevel mixed-effects complementary log-log regression, GLMs, vanilla and ordered logistic/probit, Poisson and negative binomial regression, and parametric survival analysis models. You can read about replication weights in the [svy manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/svy.pdf#Page=185).